# Comparar 2 arreglos y asignar valor coincidente

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo 2 arreglos de objetos 
EL primero llamado **data**:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: 'Piero',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    nombre: 'Nelson',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    nombre: 'Diego'
  },
 ]
```

y el segundo llamado **subs**:

```
const subs = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Temprano',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'A tiempo',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Tarde'
  },
]
```

En los cuales quiero comparar que si tienen el mismo **id** el arreglo subs le pase su **name** y si no coincide que le ponga un `'-'` al arreglo **data** intente de esta forma:

```
data.forEach((d)=>{
 subs.forEach((s)=>{
   if(d.id === s.id){
     d.subname = s.name;
   }
   else {
     d.subname = '-';
    }
   });
 });
```

Pero siempre me imprime los valores con `'-'` como si no coincidiera con ninguno. Que parte estoy haciendo mal? hay otra forma mas sencilla de hacer esto? agradecería de mucho su ayuda.

**El tamaño del arreglo subs puede variar**

Comment: Pensaba lo mismo, que podría ser el tipo de dato pero son el mismo tipo e igual no funciono.

Comment: es porque lo declaras como constante, no puedes modificar una constante

Comment: y como si le llego asignar  el valor  -> '-' si era constante ? el problema es que no esta haciendo bien match con el segundo array al parecer

Comment: el '-' queda en el campo nombre ?

Comment: Si, por eso digo que al parecer no esta haciendo bien el match

Comment: Tienes razon, acabo de probarlo y funciona bien para Diego

Comment: Eso es pero deberia pasarle su valor si su id coincide con el otro pero siempre le manda el -> '-'

Comment: pregunta los objetos los que comparas viene con el mismo largo , tanto data como subs?

Comment: No, no tienen el mismo tamaño

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta el comentario de FederHico lo resolví  de esta manera:

```
data.forEach(d => {
  const match = subs.find(s => s.id === d.id);
   d.subname = match ? match.name : '-';
});
```

:D

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

En la primera iteración del foreach data, entra `id = 1` pregunta por cada uno de los items, y encuentra que hay una coincidencia, por lo cual, le asigna "Temprano" al subname de Piero; Luego de recorrer los demas y no encontrar coincidencias, empieza a recorrer nuevamente  con `id = 4`

***¿Qué pasa?***

> **Que en la primera iteración de subs con `id=4` encuentra que `id = 4 != id = 1`  por lo cual, sobreescribe el
>   valor "Temprano" que se le había asignado correctamente por "-"**

y así sucesivamente por cada item, en la última iteración, podemos ver, como quedó asignado correctamente Diego , ya que no volvió a entrar y no reemplazó el valor correcto asignado en la iteración anterior

Comment: Alguien complete con la forma correcta de hacerlo jajaj